# Angular 7 "expected 'styles' to be an array of strings"

Tags: javascript, angular, string, compiler-errors, angular7

I am trying to run my server and have my app.component.html load on localhost:8000. Instead, I am receiving this error

> compiler.js:7992 Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.
>     at assertArrayOfStrings (compiler.js:7992)
>      at >CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.j>s.CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata >>(compiler.js:17325)
>      at >CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.j>s.CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (compiler.js:17970)
>      at compiler.js:17630
>      at Array.map ()
>      at >CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.j>s.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:17630)
>      at >JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompile>r._loadModules (compiler.js:24899)
>      at >JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompile>r._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:24880)
>      at >JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompile>r.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:24840)
>      at CompilerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser->dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync >>(platform-browser-dynamic.js:143)

I tried messing around with the syntax and checked my angular.json file.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'public';
}
```

Any idea on how to solve this? This is blocking me from loading my google

Comment: can you show which modules you included in your main app module?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Stylesheets which are referenced in your `angular.json`'s `styles[]` cannot be referenced in a Component's `styleUrls[]` decorator.

Make sure that you are not referencing `./app.component.css` in both files.

Comment: this worked for me. The stylesheets in angular.json should not be duplicated in your component's styleUrls []. If duplicated, the bundling doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 11):

I got this as well in the process of upgrading to Angular 7 and upgrading various dependencies to their latest versions. I found that using raw-loader version 2.0.0 was causing this error even though my styleUrls were correct syntax. Downgrading to raw-loader version 1.0.0 resolved this issue. I don't know if this helps in your situation.

Comment: It does answer the question though. Question is `Any idea how to solve this?` and this is an idea about it which actually helped me as it was also due to updated dependency for me.

Comment: This solved my issue, but how you figure out that raw loader version causes this?

Comment: I faced the problem when trying to upgrade many dependencies to latest. At first the error message made no sense and after searching SO for solutions to no avail, I went back and upgraded one (or a few) dependencies at a time until I got the error, went back and forth until I narrowed it down to exactly this library.

Comment: This is still the issue and thanx for providing your solution... downgrading the version works for me!

Comment: This solved my problem while doing an ng5 -> ng8 upgrade. My raw-loader was at v4.0.0. I downgraded to v1.0.0. I worry about missing out on functionality by going back 3 major releases. Anyone care to comment?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This raw loader read page as a string when import is used.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it happened because in the multi-repo project the incorrect loader has been used during the Angular build process (`raw-loader@2`), so I had to add the correct loader to Angular project dependencies:

```
devDependencies: {
    ...
    raw-loader: "^1.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same console error, spent a few days reading every hit on Google...

Solved!

The story:
I had to add functionality to an existing Angular project.  When I performed git clone, ng serve, open browser -> error assert....

I decided to upgrade to Angular 8 and see if the problem goes away, and it didn't.  Eventually, I created a new Angular 8 app using "ng new ..."

Compared package.json and angular.json of both existing and new project.  I found out, the brand new Angular app, had no *loader* packages In package.json, while the existing did have.  Also the existing project was specifying a webpack devDependancy, i removed all loaders, and webpack, deleted package-lock.json and node_modules folder -> npm install.

Solved.  I guess there is some bit of code that was being forced to a specific version, conflicting with what Angular really needs.

Answer (score 1):

changing scss loader in webpack.config.js fixed it for me.
It should look like this:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.global\.scss$/],
  use: ["to-string-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
}
```

and in package json:

```
"to-string-loader": "^1.1.6",
"css-loader": "^3.4.2",
"sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
```

Answer (score -3):

It sounds to me that you are missing the square brackets around your styles.scss file reference in you angular.json file.

It should look like this:

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.scss"
],
```