# How to load templates in angular Hybrid application?

Tags: angularjs, angular-hybrid

I have recently migrated the app from angular 1.7 to Angular 8. On loading the application it was unable to load the templates.
Then I used require('./tempalte-name') in the directives to load. But then it gave exception that 
"Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)"

I used raw-loader in this way => require('raw-loader!./template-name')
There were no errors in the console. But in the browser window, the template is being shown as [object Module].

When I replace the require('raw-loader!./template-name') with raw template e.g 'Test'. It displays correctly

Is there any way to get the template html instead of [object Module].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
// @ts-ignore
import * as TEMPLATE from 'raw-loader!./myComponent.html';
...
{
  ...
  template: TEMPLATE.default
  ...
}
```

Int works fine for me (angularjs + angular9 + angular-cli)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this - was looking for a solution that worked in Angular8/9, as template: require('!raw-loader!./path') wasn't working after upgrading from Angular 7 - your solution appears to be working though!

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading **@angular-devkit/build-angular** to version **0.802.2**.

Since **0.803.0** it shows [object Module]

Or you can try completely different approach - instead of using **template: require()** you can use **templateUrl** but then you have to copy html files to destination folder.

To do that, you have to change angular.json and set assets

```
{
    "glob": "**/*.html",
    "input": "apps/lopa/src/app-ajs",
    "output": "/app-ajs"
},
```

And in your component use full path like this:

```
templateUrl: 'app-ajs/components/component-name.html'
```

Comment: I downgraded the version. But after that I am getting the following error in the console.  **"Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings"**.   Is there any another dependency that needs to the downgraded ?

Comment: That is probably not connected to this issue. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54164830/12704028