# Angular 8: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a recently upgraded Angular app (Angular v7 => v8) and everything used to work just fine.

But now, after switching to 8, I get an error in my login function (below).   The error is most likely easy to resolve,  but the stack trace makes little sense.   It doesn't show where the type error actually happens, except for in the vendor code.

I tried to take a few stabs in the dark at fixing it, such as resolving the promise returned from `this.router.navigate`, turning the subscribe into a promise, adding a console.log to the auth guard to see if it stops there (it doesn't) and finally, I added some logging code to my screen (screen after login), and nothing was getting logged.

Has anyone run into this?  I reviewed the upgrade notes and didn't see anything stick out.    If anybody has any tips to figure out where this is happening, I can take it from there.

**Login Code:**

```
    this.clearAlerts();
    localStorage.setItem('persistLogin', this.persistLogin.toString());
    this.svc
      .login(this.user).subscribe((res: ApiResponse) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.router.navigate([res.action.href]);
      }, err => {
          console.log(err);
        this.error = err.error.message;
        if (err.error.action) {
          this.links.resolve(err.error);
        }
      }, () => console.log('done'));
  }
```

**Error Message**:

Happens after done.

```
    core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
        at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:27)
        at from (from.js:9)
        at Observable._subscribe (defer.js:14)
        at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
        at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
        at TakeOperator.call (take.js:22)
        at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:23)
        at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)
        at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:59)
        at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:53)
        at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:793)
        at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:752)
        at zone-evergreen.js:854
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:400)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
        at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
        at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:570)
        at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:485)
        at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1596)
```

*EDIT* - Login Svc Code added.

Login Svc Code - Note, I tried removing this and got the same error

```
login(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(`${environment.api}/account/login`, user).pipe(
      map((res: ApiResponse) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', res.payload);
        return res;
      }),
      map(
        (res: ApiResponse) => {
          const timer$ = timer(0, REFRESH_INTERVAL);
          this.$isAuthenticated = timer$.pipe(
            switchMap(_ => this.getIsAuthenticated()),
            shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE)
          );
          return res;
        },
        map((res: ApiResponse) => {
          const timer$ = timer(0, REFRESH_INTERVAL);
          this.$user = timer$.pipe(
            switchMap(_ => this.getSelf()),
            shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE)
          );
          return res;
        })
    )
    );
  }
```

*EDIT 2* Add Home Component

Home Component Code (M

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../../models/user.model';
import { AppService } from '../../services/app.service';
import { IState } from '../../store/reducers';
import { selectApp } from '../../store/selectors/app.selectors';
import { IAppState } from './../../store/state/app.state';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  homeContent = [];
  user: User;
  contentSub: Subscription;
  sub: Subscription;
  appState$ = this._store.pipe(select(selectApp));
  state: IAppState;
  constructor(private svc: AppService, private _store: Store<IState>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('123');
    this.contentSub = this.svc
      .getHomeContent()
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(123451232);
        this.homeContent = res.payload.items;
      });
    this.appState$.subscribe(value => {
      console.log(12345);
      this.user = value.user;
    });
  }
}
```

Selector Code:

```
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { IState } from '../reducers';
import { IAppState } from '../state/app.state';

const appState = (state: IState) => state.app;

export const selectApp = createSelector(
  appState,
  (state: IAppState) => state.app
);
```

Environment:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.20
Node: 10.18.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14
```

Comment: From the console error, it looks like you have error in `subscribeTo.js` line 27. Can you post the subscribeTo.js snippet along with the implementation of `.login` service?

Comment: Sure, I can do that.   The reason I didn't post it originally was because I added console.logs to the subscribe code and it was getting past the console.logs and into the block that navigates to the next page

Comment: In that case, Can you post the js code for component that `res.action.href` leads to?

Comment: added.   I guess maybe the suspect could be the NgRx store code

Comment: Looks normal to me so far. Are you receiving the correct response from the server?
You can always try with console debugger to go step by step to identify where exactly the fault is instead of applying console.log everywhere. That way it will be faster and more detailed.

Comment: yes, response looks normal.   Yes, I tried with the debugger.   Seems to get as far as the router.navigate and craps out with the subscribe error.

Comment: Sorry won't be able to help much here in that case. Looks to me more like an internal code is failing and that can only be hunted with debugging the entire application.

Comment: Did you solve this Taylor? I have same problem, using same environment. I've done much the same debugging as you.

Comment: Sorry for not following up @BobC.   I posted what I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this when I found out I had a circular dependency.

I ran `ng build --aot` which threw a warning about a circular dependency in my `app.module.ts` file.

At the bottom of the file, I noticed I had:

`platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);`.   In essence referencing itself.    I did some quick googling and found out that line belongs in `main.ts`.

Moved the line and the problem went away.

Comment: Thanks Taylor! This did not solve my problem. My app.module.ts and main.ts were already correct. But, my problem was solved by this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095476/angular-7-expected-styles-to-be-an-array-of-strings

Comment: @BobC try doing an aot build.   that seems to surface more errors and hints